# Highlight A1 based on A2:A400 data

Tags: excel

This should be fairly simple and straight forward but I am unable to figure it out.

Cell A1 is a Title Cell.

Cells A2:A400 contain the data, numbers in this case.

> *I simply want to highlight Cell A1 when any value in the range is <>*
> *0.*

It works if I use a single cell, but will not work with the range.

```
=A91<>0 "This works to highlight A1"
```

```
=A2:A400<>0 "This does not work to highlight A1"
```

I realize I should most likely be using an OR or IF statement, but can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: May be something like this : `=ROWS(A2:A400)-COUNTIF(A2:A400,"<>0")` or may be this `=COUNTIFS(A2:A400,0)`

Comment: `=OR(A2:A400<>0)` ?

Comment: @user11222393 i think that will highlight irrespective of any. Could you confirm once by testing in excel

Comment: With the `COUNTIFS()` it would be like this to highlight cell `A1` if any cells not equal to `0` --> `=COUNTIFS(A2:A400,0)=0` so what it does when there is a zero it returns a count then compares is it equal to `0` if yes then highlights else doesnt

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya "highlight Cell A1 when any value in the range is <> 0" sounds like at least one value in given range is not equal to 0. Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: OR is the shortest, otherwise I think you'd have to use =COUNTIFS(A2:A400,"<>0",A2:A400,"<>")

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, `OR()` certainly doesn't works here. I have tested the same.

Comment: It does work for me, with the caveat that it will find anything not blank or zero including letters as will my suggestion of countifs.

Comment: If empty strings need to be taken account `=OR(A2:A400<>0,A2:A400="")` would work I think. @MayukhBhattacharya statement is _highlight Cell A1 when any value in the range is <> 0._ `<> 0` means not equal to `0` so "highlight Cell A1 when ANY value in the range is not equal to 0". That is how I understand it. Your formula highlights `A1` only if there are no 0's at all

Comment: No no `OR()` is not clearly working in this I have tested in `Excel` before commenting. Please show me a `.gif` how it is working. When I used this formula in conditional formatting it doesnt highlights the cell `A1` --> `=OR(A2:A400<>0)`

Comment: Not sure - we may be over-thinking it! Another simple one that works for my reading of the question is =COUNTIF(A2:A400,">0")

Comment: @TomSharpe it wouldn't highlight if there are negative numbers

Comment: OP has clearly stated there shouldn't be so much confusion: `I simply want to highlight Cell A1 when any value in the range is <> 0`  .So, which means the OP is asking to highlight cell `A1` when any value in the range `A2:A400` is not equal to zero. Which means if the range has no zero at all should highlight else not

Comment: Oh, now I see what we interpret differently! I think in that case it would say "_every_ value not equal to 0". I understand "_any_ value not equal to 0" as at least 1 value not equal to 0. I guess we should wait for OP to clarify

Comment: This is how understood abt OP's [Any](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184322/what-is-the-difference-between-any-or-every)

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the cell <kbd>A1</kbd> when there is no zero in the range `A2:A400`. Using `Conditional Formatting` with `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()`.

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A400,0)=0
```

---

**Steps:**

- Select cell <kbd>A1</kbd>
- From `Home` Tab --> Under `Styles` Group --> Click on `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` ( I have used shortcut to open --> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- The above opens the `New Formatting Rule` window
- Click on the last rule --> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- In the edit the rule description enter the above formula.
- Click on `Format` --> Choose preferred formatting.
- Click `OK`

---

**Note:** I have shown with a shorter range for one can view working of the conditional formatting, but that should work for the given range in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well for what it's worth my preference assuming I'm reading the question correctly would be either

```
 =COUNTIF(A:A,">0")+COUNTIF(A:A,"<0")
```

or

```
=COUNT(A:A)-COUNTIF(A:A,0)
```

because these ignore any text that might be present including the header and work OK with full-column references.

[image]

So this would cause highlighting because there are some numbers not equal to zero

[image]

and this wouldn't because there are some numbers and text but the numbers are all zero:

[image]